# Placing "too" in a sentence

Tags: also-too

> This too shall pass.

Would anyone help me to understand why in this common saying the "too" word is placed in the middle of the sentence? Referring to Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_too_shall_pass).

> *This shall pass too.*

Wouldn't it be more natural to place the "too" in the end of the clause, as it usually done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too* in this sense *(also, as well)* refers to the subject of the sentence, so is placed immediately after it. This is a rather formal, literary usage. The Wikipedia article indicates that your phrase comes from literature. In everyday conversation you would probably say things like "Can I come too?" "I've got one too."

https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/i-too